# Why am I getting a type error reading in files in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tried searching but haven't found the same issue.

After updating PyCharm I'm unable to run the below code without getting a type error.

Have tried reinstalling/updating Anaconda, but still getting the below error now.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import time

path = r'filepath'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xlsx'))

individual_df = (pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files)
combined_df = pd.concat(individual_df, ignore_index=True)
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4d7281cf16f8> in <module>
      1 material_usage_individual_df = (pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files)
----> 2 combined_usage = pd.concat(material_usage_individual_df, ignore_index=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    283     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    284     """
--> 285     op = _Concatenator(
    286         objs,
    287         axis=axis,


TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xWidnow'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that somewhere in the code you have misspelled xWidnow. Should be xWindow